# i need fast and convenient way to organize table data in-memory

Tags: c#, .net, dictionary, datatable, hashtable

Initial conditions:

```
DateTime moment

string key

double value
```

somewhere across the code i want to

```
Add("2010.08.09 12:55:34", "px_ValX", 10);
Add("2010.08.09 12:55:35", "px_ValX", 1);
Add("2010.08.09 12:55:35", "px_ValY", 12);
Add("2010.08.09 12:55:35", "px_ValZ", 100);
Add("2010.08.09 12:55:38", "px_ValZ", 5);
```

and then i want to get table from that data array

```
DataTable ToTable()
```

which produces

```
date|px_valX|px_ValY|px_ValZ
"2010.08.09 12:55:34"|10|0|0
"2010.08.09 12:55:35"|1|12|100
"2010.08.09 12:55:38"|0|0|5
```

Also it would be awesome if i could do fast

```
double Get(DateTime moment, string key)
```

and

```
DataTable Get(string key)
```

which produces the following table

```
data|value
"2010.08.09 12:55:34"|10
```

It's rather SQL task, but i need in-memory data structure. I plan to use C# DataTable class and its Select method, but i think there is more fast and convenient way.

Right on this moment i use the following class in my app

```
[Serializable]
public class CalcItem
{
    public CalcItem()
    {
        Additional = new Dictionary<string, double>();
    }
    public Dictionary<string, double> Additional { get; set; }

    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
}
```

and in CalcItemManager

```
public List<CalcItem> CalcItems { get; set; }
```

To add data i do

```
var clc = new CalcItem();
clc.Additional.Add("px_ValX", 10);
_dataManager.CalcItems.Add(clc);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here is my another question that overheads this one and is a solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4003019/what-is-faster-and-more-convenient-hashtable-or-dictionaryint-double)