# What is faster and more convenient: Hashtable or Dictionary<int, double>()?

Tags: c#, .net, data-structures, memory-management

Preamble: I'm working at heavy-loaded applicaion that produces large data arrays.

I wrote the following class

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    namespace CSharpSampleApplication.Data.CoreObjects
    {
        [Serializable]
        public class CalcItem
        {
            public CalcItem()
            {
                _additional = new Hashtable();
            }

            private readonly Hashtable _additional;

            public bool ContainsKey(int id)
            {
                return _additional.ContainsKey(id);
            }

            public void Add(int id, double value)
            {
                _additional.Add(id, value);
            }

            public DateTime Date { get; set; }

            public object this[int id]
            {
                get
                {
                    return _additional[id];
                }
            }
        }


    }
```

Then, in another class, i made manager which contains the following:

```
    public List<CalcItem> CalcItems{ get; private set;}
    private readonly Dictionary<string, int> _keys;
    private int _index;
    private readonly object  _lock = new object();

    public int GetIndex(string key)
    {
        lock (_lock)
        {
            if (_keys.ContainsKey(key))
                return _keys[key];
            else
            {
                _index++;
                _keys.Add(key, _index);
                return _index;
            }
        }
    }
```

By using those classes i log some realtime data, for example like this:

```
                var clc = new CalcItem();
                clc.Date = DateTime.Now;
                clc.Add(_calcItemManager.GetIndex("testData"), r.Next() / 100.00);
                clc.Add(_calcItemManager.GetIndex("testData1"), r.Next() / 100.00);

                i++;

                if (i % 25 == 0)
                {
                    clc.Add(_calcItemManager.GetIndex("testData2"), r.Next()/100.00);
                    clc.Add(_calcItemManager.GetIndex("testData3"), r.Next()/100.00);
                    clc.Add(_calcItemManager.GetIndex("testData4"), r.Next()/100.00);
                    clc.Add(_calcItemManager.GetIndex("testData5"), r.Next()/100.00);
                }
                _calcItemManager.Add(clc);
```

So the manager stores [string key]-[int index] bindings for all the calcItems.

The question is:
Is it better to use `Dictionary<int, double>` instead of Hashtable() to optimize memory usage and faster perfomance?
List Items - contains about 1.000.000 records
CalcItem.Additional - contains about 5 - 10 records

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The obly way to answer "faster" is to time it for **your** typical data. However the dictionary is more convenient (no need to cast) and efficient (no boxing).

If the data keys are *contiguous*, however, it would be better just to use a List-of-double, and use the key as the index (with offset if your data doesn't start at 0).

Comment: The best! List-of-double - incredible idea - see my answer and new CalcItem class!!! Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

I think the accepted answer to [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1089132/net-hashtable-vs-dictionary-can-the-dictionary-be-as-fast) also answers your question.

In brief, both data structures will have very similar performance in most situations. If it's important for you, you can (and should) measure.

Answer (score 0):

Marc Gravell - awsome decision with List-of-double!!! How could i miss that?!
Memory reduced twice!
Here is my new code:

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    namespace CSharpSampleApplication.Data.CoreObjects
    {
        [Serializable]
        public class CalcItem
        {
            public CalcItem()
            {
                _additional = new List<double>();
            }

            private readonly List<double> _additional;

            public bool ContainsKey(int id)
            {
                return _additional.Count - 1 >= id;
            }

            public void Add(int id, double value)
            {
                if(ContainsKey(id))
                    _additional[id] = value;
                else
                {
                    while (!ContainsKey(id))
                    {
                        _additional.Add(0);
                    }
                    _additional[id] = value;
                }
            }

            public DateTime Date { get; set; }

            public object this[int id]
            {
                get
                {
                    return _additional[id];
                }
            }
        }


    }
```